# How does this script generate an IP address randomly?

Tags: shell-script, shell

Can someone explain me how the following code works? I know it generates an IP address randomly but I don't understand how.

```
while
  set $(dd if=/dev/urandom bs=4 count=1 2>/dev/null | od -An -tu1)
  [ $1 -lt 224 ] &&
  [ $1 -ne 10 ] &&
  { [ $1 -ne 192 ] || [ $2 -ne 168 ]; } &&
  { [ $1 -ne 172 ] || [ $2 -lt 16 ] || [ $2 -gt 31 ]; }
do :; done
ip_address=$1.$2.$3.$4
```

Comment: Besides the test done in it, this will still generate IP addresses you will not find very useful to use, like `127.0.0.1`. How do you plan to use the results generated by this?

Answer (score 3):

The command

```
dd if=/dev/urandom bs=4 count=1 2>/dev/null | od -An -tu1
```

generates data like

```
     251 113 126 026
```

by asking `dd` to read four bytes from the `urandom` device  and then converting this to a series of unsigned integers of 1 byte each with `od`.

This is handed to `set` by means of a command substitution (`$(...)`), and `set` will set the positional parameters `$1`, `$2`, `$3` and `$4` to the integers.

Then there are some checks performed on these integers, and the loop continues until one of the tests fail.  The `:` in the loop body is a no-op and is only needed to satisfy the grammar of the shell.

---

Another way to generate random IP addresses (not in private address ranges):

```
$ nmap -n -iR 10 -sL | awk '/report for/ { print $NF }'
221.37.208.42
121.3.97.158
203.225.119.103
145.139.220.88
95.153.25.126
149.73.57.221
165.178.177.39
11.187.21.175
175.211.240.124
130.89.42.47
```

Comment: So the command dd if=/dev/urandom bs=4 count=1 2>/dev/null | od -An -tu1 generates numbers from 0 to 255, right?. Can you explain to me 2>/dev/null what exactly does it do?

Comment: @user299485 It redirects stderr (any error, progress, diagnostic, etc. messages from `dd`) to `/dev/null`, i.e., discards them. In this case dd's "1+0 records in/out" messages. (Adding `status=none` would have probably been better.)

Answer (score 1):

Like Kusalananda says, the `dd | od` sets `$1..$4` to four random 8-bit integers, which can be taken as the four octets of an IPv4 address.

The tests in your script, however, look odd. Remember the loop repeats as long as the tests are true, or ends when any of them *fails*. The first test then compares the first octet against 224, and *fails* when it's equal to or larger than it. Thus, you'll get IP addresses greater or equal to `224.0.0.0`. These are all multicast or reserved addresses, so it's hard to see what practical use the generator has.

The other tests will accept the private-use ranges, too, but they're much smaller than `224..255` so you'll hardly see any.

If the intent is to generate routable addresses, the sense of the tests should be inverted.

---

As for `od -An -tu1`, [the man page explaines the switches](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/od.1.html). `-An` prevents printing addresses, `-tu1` takes the input as one-byte unsigned integers:

> `-A, --address-radix=RADIX`
>                 output format for file offsets; RADIX is one of `[doxn]`, for Decimal, Octal, Hex or None
>
> `-t, --format=TYPE`
>   TYPE is made up of one or more of these specifications:
>    `u[SIZE]`
>                 unsigned decimal, SIZE bytes per integer

Comment: Yeah. I started trying to explain what the tests actually _did_ (I think they want to avoid private address ranges), but they were too odd for me to make proper sense of.